# How to get Views caching working with contextual filters?

Tags: views, caching, performance

Using Drupal 7.19 and Views 3.5 cache is not respecting contextual filter argument- it is displaying the same cache result no matter what argument given. How to get this working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Views bug actually and it is not solved yet, but you can work around it by using this patch if you are using contextual filter [Taxonomy with depth](http://drupal.org/node/1430650#comment-6961132) as I guess, and if it didn't work you can turn off the "Field Language" for the view if you have neutral language content, but this patch is not complete as there is some issues not solve, you can see the full discussion of this issue here [issue here](http://drupal.org/node/1055616)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed since 7.x-3.8

Resolution comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1055616#comment-8611373

Comment: I am on 7.x-3.13 and see this very same issue.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/fixing-caching-views-exposed-filters-drupal-7) talks about this problem and has a patch to solve

Answer (score 1):

Just try this module: [Views argument cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_arg_cache)

EDIT: You also have this module available [Views custom cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_custom_cache)